# How to host two self contained static sites system with apache webserver running wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, apache, web, devops

I am new to web administration. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Current setup -** 
A web server hosting example.com (WordPress site). Now, a self contained static content folder (fu) is located in this location on the webserver: **/var/www/html/(Website_Code__Folder_Deployed_from_SCM)/wp-content/uploads/fu**
And, if you browse, **www.example.com/fu**, you would see that self contained static help system for the website.

**Requirement -** 
I have another self contained help static website (test) which is required to be hosted in a similar way as the fu website.

**What I did:**

1. I went to the same location on the server /var/www/html/(Website_Code__Folder_Deployed_from_SCM)/wp-content/uploads and then uploaded the 'test' folder their with a thought that if I browse www.example.com/test I would see that static help website however instead I got a 404.
2. I also performed the same on IIS and I was able to see both the static websites with localhost/fu and localhost/test after enabling "Directory Browsing"
   Please note, /var/www/html/(Website_Code__Folder_Deployed_from_SCM)/wp-content/uploads/ has all the files of fu scattered inside uploads folder.
3. Unfortunately, I could not make much sense from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188120/how-do-i-serve-static-content-on-same-domain-as-wordpress

**Any pointers to resources that can help understand the request flow through Apache & WordPress would be great.**

Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a very broad questions with many possible answers but here are some options:

1. Check the permissions on the test folder and the contents of the 'test' folder. They should match the settings of the 'fu' folder. If the permissions don't match, fix them using chown/chmod commands.
2. If the permissions match but the content still doesn't work, you may need to dig deeper into the .htaccess files in those directories (could be anywhere in the tree under /var/www/html) or into the apache configuration files themselves (possibly in /etc/apache /etc/apache2 /etc/httpd)
3. Ideally you should, IMO, create some dedicated directories for this content under /var/www/ and modify the apache config files to serve the content as you intended, probably using Aliases ([Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#outside)). This way you can manage and deploy and manage the content separately from the Wordpress.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to fix it. In the error logs I found that the httpd was actually expecting an index.html file however what was actually present inside the static website folder was just index.htm. I renamed it to index.html and it served the static website contents just fine.
This is the error:
Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/ep-corp-develop-82e95bed3cc7276c1d4a6f5c5a92b1ba04cdf0f0/wp-content/upload s/scenchronize_help/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive